windows 11 - how to stop antimalware service executable from running?
I have a Windows 11 partition on my PC and I noticed that the antimalware service never stops running, or never while I'm working at least and keeps using well over 100MB of RAM constantly. It's so frustrating, it doesn't even stop when I turn off protection in settings and I think I tried EVERYTHING on the internet to kill it, from services.msc to regedit.
I don't know what to do anymore, I even got NSudo which was supposed to work cause it gives some elevated privileges, and I followed this tutorial that makes a script to shut off Windows Defender but that worked only like once and now even when I open Task Manager under NSudo with all elevated privileges, I can't shut off the antimalware because access is denied.
Edit: I got Bitdefender and it's behaving much better. Thanks for everyone's input.

You could always use a different anti-virus software. // 100-200 MiB memory usage isn’t really all that much. If this is already critical for you, you should look into upgrading your RAM.

Like @DanielB said the anti-virus software doesn't use that much memory and it is very risky to turn it off, if you have performance issue I suggest you try a sfc /scannow first to see if any windows file have been corrupted.

I have 16 GB of RAM and it's not really an issue, it just bugs me that it keeps CONSTANTLY running and while I'm doing some more memory-cpu intensive things and it gives me little lags sometimes, just for a split second but they're frustrating when they keep happening. I know the risks, I would just like it to stop scanning ALL the time. Like once and then done would be nice.

Which antimalware suite? For Defender, just stop Realtime Protection -- which is a bad idea to do for more than a few seconds.

@DrMoishePippik it's the original windows defender. I tried stopping real-time protection, Antimalware Service Executable in Task Manager keeps running.

I think you're focusing on the wrong set of symptoms. Is your concern system load? Windows Defender is one of the better AV products with minimal system load, though there may be others that are slightly better. You can try tuning the system rather than trying to disable it, as tuning IS a support configuration while disabling is NOT.

I suggest re-presenting your post focusing on the question BEHIND the question you've asked here. It is likely we can find you a better solution that satisfies both good security AND good performance.
